# Azure VM Backup strategy

Tags: azure, backup

I currently use Azure snapshots to backup my Azure-hosted Windows servers.  The problem is that if my Azure-hosted Windows VM fails restoring a snapshot can take hours.  That is way too much downtime.  Is there a solution that will let me backup an Azure VM and restore it directly to Azure that is faster and/or better than the built-in Azure snapshotting?

Comment: You can look on Azure Backup https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/tutorial-backup-vm-at-scale and Azure Site Recovery https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/azure-to-azure-tutorial-enable-replication

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [Azure IaaS VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/quick-backup-vm-portal) backup to backup and restore your VMs. Azure backups can be created through the Azure portal. This method provides a browser-based user interface to create and configure Azure backups and all related resources. You can protect your data by taking backups at regular intervals. Azure Backup creates recovery points that can be stored in geo-redundant recovery vaults. This article details how to back up a virtual machine (VM) with the Azure portal.

Comment: Thanks Vikranth.  We currently use Azure snapshots.  However it takes several hours to restore a snapshot.  IF we are recovering from a crashed server that is too long to wait.  So I was trying to find some backup solution with faster recovery times